# How I add a JLabel to a JFrame on another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I'm new to coding, and I'm having this problem: I would like to add a `JLabel` to a `JFrame` I created in a different class. Here is the code. I don't understand how to properly do it, but I'd know how do it if they were in the same method.

Map:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Map {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map();

    }

    private static void map() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Run Kitty Run!");
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(1000, 500);

    }

}
```

Cat:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Cat 
{
    //instance variables
    ImageIcon pic;

    public Cat()
    {
        //constructor
        pic = new ImageIcon("/Users/dell/Desktop/runKittyRun/cat.png");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(pic);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I tried doing windows.add(label) and it didn't work.. :/

Comment: This is way too advanced for you since you're just beginning. All that was required was an instance of Map.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, don't, kind of...

You have two basic choices, you can either allow `Cat` to provide the required information for `Map` to decide who best it should be displayed, for example, having a getter which returns the image

Or, you could design `Cat` so it's easily addable to `Map`

```
public class Cat extends JPanel
{
    //instance variables
    ImageIcon pic;

    public Cat()
    {
        //constructor
        // Absolute file references are a bad idea by the way
        pic = new ImageIcon("/Users/dell/Desktop/runKittyRun/cat.png");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel(pic);
        add(label);
    }

}
```

Then simply create an instance of `Cat` when you need it and add it to what ever container you want...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Map {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Map();
    }

    private static void map() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Cat());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this counts for any variable or method, not just JLabel. Let's start by calling these methods methodOne, and methodTwo. methodOne will be in a class called One (I won't bother writing out the class body, I'm doing this from my iPod)

```
JLabel jl;
public void methodOne(){
    jl = // blah blah blah;
}
```

Ok, so now you want to use jl in the second method. So here's what to do:

```
public void methodTwo(){
    One o = new One();
    JFrame j = // instance of JFrame;
    j.add(o.jl);
}
```

Remember: the JLabel variable was in the class One, so I instantiated one.

Hope that helped